# Trouble understanding how angularjs $httpDefaultCache, $cacheFactory and how to access that data

Tags: angularjs, caching

I'm having to inline all resources into one file and this includes all the data that my application uses. With a gulp process, I've been able to create a $cacheFactory with all the data:

```
angular.module('app').run('$cacheFactory', '$http', function($cacheFactory, $http){
  var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
  $httpDefaultCache.put('/data/names.json',{...});
  $httpDefaultCache.put('/data/places.json',{...});
});
```

My understanding of how to access this instead of making a call externally (file) may be incorrect.

I thought that by setting $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true, that my request to the endpoints of above would use the default cache.

```
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
    }]);
```

Instead I get an error of

```
https://.../data/names.json 404 (Not Found)
```

As if it is looking within the the client and not in angular's cache. The type is also an xhr.

```
  data.load(names, '/data/names.json');
   ...
 function load(broadcastName, url, force){



    if(!isLoaded[broadcastName] && !force){

        console.log('Loading name data from', url);

        // Make the http GET request
        http({

            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: true

        }).then(function success(response){
            console.log("response: ", response)
            ...
        })
```

Had to create a custom http request that perfectly imitates angular $http service. It is used in several other applications we have, so I know it works. Only thing that has been added for this implenation is cache:true.

I've looked at several other questions that were similar, but I am still not understanding how it is working. How does using http default cache work? And is there something I should be aware of that I may be glossing over?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please, provide the code where you perform requests, don't try to describe it.

Comment: I've added some code of what the request are. I don't think it will be very clear as I have to omit some things. There's an application created by a previous dev that works great and accesses the Angular cache using this method, but I've been unable to recreate it. So am looking for an explanation on how to set/access Angular cache so requests access that instead of attempting to access clients.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special term for `$http` cache like '$httpDefaultCache'. It works like you expect it to work. You set *either* `$httpProvider.defaults.cache` or `cache` request option to true, and the response is retrieved from `$http` cache, which is available by default as `$cacheFactory.get('$http')`.

Cache is just key/value storage. If request URL doesn't match a key completely, cache won't be used.

[Here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0eDE6XXLbEdgpUpTCLpC?p=preview) how it works:

```
  $cacheFactory.get('$http').put('/foo', 'foo');

  $http({ url: '/foo', cache: true })
  .then(result => {
    $scope.foo = result.data;
  })
  .catch(result => console.error(result))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into it more then. Perhaps there is an error in spelling I'm not seeing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Either that, or `.run('$cacheFactory' ...` runs after `load(...)` somehow. There are not so many possibilities to choose from.

Comment: Right, I've done this once before with no problems, but I'm unable to replicate it. I am loading the .run('$cacheFactory' ... code after the load(...) code, I'll see if that could be causing an issue. However in previous apps, I am loading all templateCache and cacheFactory files after main application, and it works. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: You're welcome The snippet in the OP lacks the context. They may be loaded in different order, but the thing that matters is if  load(...) is executed in another run block or somewhere else (e.g. a controller).

Comment: So I found that the issue was with the data. In the process of placing it in the caching, a module called jsesc was basically escaping some of the data which made it break. Good to know I was on the right track and great that you helped me double check some things!.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Consider accepting the answer if your case is solved.